# Испольование DBM файлов в Perl

Tags: perl

Всех приветствую. Вот код программы:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Скрипт для загрузки программ через Wine\n";
%base = ();
dbmopen (%base, "wine", 0744) ||
die "Ошибка обкрытия DBM файла: $!";
print "Программы, которые можно запустить:\n";
foreach (@kluch = keys %base)
{print $_,"\n"};
print "Введите название программы для ее запуска или
клавишу 'Q' для заполнения базы данных\n";
chomp ($komanda = <STDIN>);
if ($komanda eq 'Q' || $komanda eq 'q')
{while (1) 
    {print "Заполняем базу. Введите название программы: ";
    chomp ($imja_progr = <STDIN>);
    print "Программа - $imja_progr.\nТеперь введите адрес до исполняемого   файла: ";
    chomp ($adress = <STDIN>);
    print "Пpограмма - $imja_progr.\nАдрес - $adress.
Если все верно - нажмите клавишку 'Y' в противном случае 'N'\n";
    chomp ($proverka = <STDIN>);
    if ($proverka eq 'Y' || $proverka eq 'y') 
        {
        %base = ("imja_progr" => "$adress", %base);
        dbmclose (%base);
        print  "Ввод данных закончен.\n"} elsif 
        ($proverka eq 'N' || $proverka eq 'n') {next}}};
foreach (@kluch)
{if ($_ eq $komanda) 
    {system ("wine $base{$komanda}") && exit} else { print "Ошибка\n"; next}};
dbmclose (%base);
```

Суть всего в том, чтобы упростить запуск Windows программ через Wine в Linux. По задумке вначале выполнения программ выходят все ключи к программам, наббор которых и запускает соответствующие программы. Проблема в том что не получается увеличит DBM-массив: при добавлении нового элемента, старый (зараза!) удаляется!!!!! Пожалуйста просмотрите код, может кто увидит где тут ошибка и в чем проблема...... Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что, массив должен увеличиваться? И где это написано? В строке

    %base = ("imja_progr" => "$adress", %base);

заносится новое значение для ключа imja_progr. Путей для появления других ключей в %base как-то не просматривается.

Answer (score 1):

Строку:

```
%base = ("imja_progr" => "$adress", %base);
```

заменить на:

```
$base{$imja_progr} = $adress;
```

UPD: Полный текст:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Скрипт для загрузки программ через Wine\n";
dbmopen ( my %base, "wine", 0744) or die "Ошибка обкрытия DBM файла: $!";
print "Программы, которые можно запустить:\n";
printf "%s\n", $_ for keys %base;
print "Введите название программы для ее запуска или клавишу 'Q' для заполнения базы данных\n";
chomp ( my $cmd = <STDIN>);
if ( $cmd =~ /^q$/i )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        print "Заполняем базу. Введите название программы или <Ввод>, если не хотите больше ничего добавлять: ";
        chomp ( my $progName = <STDIN> );
        last unless $progName;
        print "Программа - $progName.\nТеперь введите адрес до исполняемого   файла: ";
        chomp ( my $address = <STDIN> );
        print "Пpограмма - $progName.\nАдрес - $address. Если все верно - нажмите клавишку 'Y'\n";
        chomp ( my $key = <STDIN>);
        if ( $key =~ /^y$/i)
        {
            $base{$progName} = $address;
            print  "Ввод данных закончен.\n";
        }
    }
}
if ( my $path = $base{$cmd} )
{
#        system ("wine", $path);
        printf "wine %s\n", $path;
}
dbmclose (%base);
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно,но эффект тот же: введенный ранее ключ и значение заменяются на новый и в массиве по прежнему тока один элемент.....

Comment: Тогда (если Вы правильно написали присваивание) попробуйте не закрывать %base во время работы (уберите dbmclose после %base=). Кстати, предложенный @Кирилл Новгородцев оператор `$base{$imja_progr}=$adress;` выглядит значительно лучше `%base = ($imja_progr=>$adress, %base);`

Comment: Спасибо уважаемому Кириллу Новгородцеву. Ваш код работает.